# Mono Projects Supporting Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: mono, raspberry-pi

Are there any Mono Projects with GPIO access that have been tested on the Raspberry Pi 2 and work ?

Comment: Have you checked out this? http://pisharp.codeplex.com/

Comment: I have.  I downloaded the library and tried using it with the Pi 2.  It did not work so I was wondering if it's something that I am doing or if it is not Pi 2 compatible. Lex Li, have you used this library on the Pi 2 successfully ?

Comment: Ping the developers via CodePlex or debug the code.